# How To Use Decimals Of An Integer

Tags: c, integer, double, decimal

I would like overpay to display overpay as the total amount paid if the result was not rounded. `calculateMonths` must be an integer which makes this much more difficult. I tried using

```
double dblCalculateMonths = (double)calculateMonths(principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment);
```

but it did not work properly. I am not sure how to fix this problem while keeping calculateMonths as an integer. Help would be very much appreciated!

I would like the results to look like this:

```
** Welcome to the CPSC 1010-S3 Payment Calculator **
Enter the principal amount: 5000.00
Enter the annual interest rate (in %): 15.0
Enter the monthly payment: 100.00
Calculating...
Total # of months needed to pay off: 79
App roximate # of years needed to pay off: 6.6
Total interest paid: $2900.00
Total amount paid: $7900.00
You overpaid: $4.43
```

But the last line displays as

```
You overpaid: $100.00
```

I am not sure how to change this. My list of code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int calculateMonths(double principal,double annualInterestRate,double monthlyPayment)
{
    double x = ((log(monthlyPayment)-log(monthlyPayment-annualInterestRate/1200.0*principal))/log(annualInterestRate/1200.0+1.0));
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    double principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment;


    printf("** Welcome to the Payment Calculator **\n\n");

    printf("Enter the principal amount:\t\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &principal);

    printf("Enter the annual interest rate (in%%):\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &annualInterestRate);

    printf("Enter the monthly payment:\t\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &monthlyPayment);

    printf("\nCalculating...\n\n");

    double roundedMonths = calculateMonths(principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment)+1;
    printf("Total # of months needed to pay off:\t\t %.0f\n", roundedMonths);

    double years = roundedMonths/12;
    printf("Approcimate # of years needed to pay off: \t %.1f\n", years);

    double amountPaid = roundedMonths * monthlyPayment;
    double interestPaid = amountPaid-principal;

    printf("Total interest paid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", interestPaid);
    printf("Total amount paid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", amountPaid);

    double dblCalculateMonths = (double)calculateMonths(principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment);
    double overpay = amountPaid - dblCalculateMonths*monthlyPayment;
    printf("You overpaid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", overpay);

    printf("%f", dblCalculateMonths);

    printf("\n\n");



    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Decimals of an integer? Wait, what?

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1) What we must input to the 3 `scanf` to reproduce the behaviour you are talking about 2) What exactly you expect or would like to have (for example, the value of a certain variable) 3) what happens instead. As your question looks now, it is hard to understand what you want. The title is also very confusing, as an integer has no decimals (by definition of integer!)

Comment: Do you have a question?  _but it did not work properly_ is not very specific.  Have you run this in a debugger with break points to view intermediate results?

Comment: So the function calculateMonths must be an integer. However, I must calculate the amount overpaid. I believe this is found by taking the decimal of calculateMonths (the unrounded value) and multiplying it by the monthly payment, then subtracting that from the total amount paid.

Comment: `calculateMonths` returns an `int`. `int` types do not have fractions. Why are you expecting an `int` type to have fractions?

Comment: Better to use `ceil(CalculateMonths(...))` rather than `CalculateMonths(...)+1`

Answer (score 1):

what's the logic in keeping calculateMonths() an integer? make it a double and it should work.

```
double calculateMonths(double principal,double annualInterestRate,double monthlyPayment)
```

and make roundedMonths an integer. Also you could add 0.5 to have the right round.

```
int roundedMonths = calculateMonths(principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment)+0.5;
printf("Total # of months needed to pay off:\t\t %d\n", roundedMonths);
```

LE: Try this:

```
int calculateMonths(double principal,double annualInterestRate,double monthlyPayment, double *dblCalculateMonths)
{
    *dblCalculateMonths = ((log(monthlyPayment)-log(monthlyPayment-annualInterestRate/1200.0*principal))/log(annualInterestRate/1200.0+1.0));
    return *dblCalculateMonths;
}

int main()
{
    double principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment, dblCalculateMonths;


    printf("** Welcome to the Payment Calculator **\n\n");

    printf("Enter the principal amount:\t\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &principal);

    printf("Enter the annual interest rate (in%%):\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &annualInterestRate);

    printf("Enter the monthly payment:\t\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &monthlyPayment);

    printf("\nCalculating...\n\n");

    double roundedMonths = calculateMonths(principal, annualInterestRate, monthlyPayment, &dblCalculateMonths)+1;
    printf("Total # of months needed to pay off:\t\t %.0f\n", roundedMonths);

    double years = roundedMonths/12;
    printf("Approcimate # of years needed to pay off: \t %.1f\n", years);

    double amountPaid = roundedMonths * monthlyPayment;
    double interestPaid = amountPaid-principal;

    printf("Total interest paid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", interestPaid);
    printf("Total amount paid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", amountPaid);

    double overpay = amountPaid - dblCalculateMonths*monthlyPayment;
    printf("You overpaid:\t\t\t\t $%.2f\n", overpay);

    printf("%f", dblCalculateMonths);

    printf("\n\n");



    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is a project for school and the only variable specified is the function calculateMonths, which must be an integer. I am not sure the logic. Also I do not want to round down, as a bank would probably not round down while you are paying a loan, but thank you!

Comment: "add 0.5 to have the right round" fails for many cases.  Better to use `round(x)` to round a `double`.